# CSS center content in relative wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-position, parallax, styling

I am making a personal website with a parallax background which takes 100% of the screen size, however when I change the screen size to the minimum size the text goes out of the div, I use a padding-top percentage. I do know quite a bit of css but I don't want to fiddle around and mess everything up, I've looked everywhere but no answer came close to my problem. Basically I just want to vertically and horizontally center my content even when I resize my screen.

Here's my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    /* whatever width you want */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 52.50%;
    /* 16:9 ratio */
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* fill parent */
    background-image: url('/storage/images/background.jpeg');
    /* let's see it! */
    color: white;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.text {
    margin-top: 15%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class=text>
                <img src="/storage/images/image.jpg" style="border-radius:100%; width:150px; height:auto;">
                <h1>My name</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle please...

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
.main {
  text-align: center;<-----------------------
  //More code..........
}

.text {
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.text img {
  border-radius:100%;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
}

.text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* whatever width you want */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 52.50%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* fill parent */
  background-image: url('http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg');
  /* let's see it! */
  color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.text img {
  border-radius:100%;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
}

.text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class=text>
                <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
                <h1>My name</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```